# How do you wire multiple lights and a split receptacle with an end-of-run switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I want to wire two lights and a split receptacle with an end-of-run switch. Here is the wiring diagram I've come up with:

[image]

Have I got this figured out right?

Comment: Yes, as ratchet freak said, looks good but the new code requires the neutral to be available at the switch location (which it looks like you are doing in the drawing) in many cases but there are exceptions to this for things like rooms that are not habitable and switches connected to raceways or accessible on the back side. Check the NEC for these exceptions or just use a three wire to the switch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perfectly by the book.

Neutral is available in the switch in case you ever want to replace it with a smart switch that needs power.

Black is always live and red is the switched live.